# Logarithmic equation's solution

Tags: logarithms

I'm unable to solve this equation further. Could someone have a shot at it and try to solve it and explain it to me please? The equation is 
$$2\log_{2}(\log_{2}(x))-\log_{2}(\log_{2}2\cdot 2^{0.5}x)=1.$$
I am trying to learn the general rule for solving this kind of log problems. So it does involve a concept and kindly donut flag it. Two people have already given me some good answers.

Comment: Is that actually $ \ (2.2)^{0.5} \ x \ $ , or is it supposed to be $ \ 2   \cdot   2^{0.5} \ x \  $ ?

Comment: Could you place parentheses around appropriate parts so as to prevent confusion?

Comment: It is $2⋅2^{0.5}.x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $\log_2(x)=X$. You have $$\log_2\frac{X^2}{3/2+X}=1=\log_2(2)$$ $$X^2=3+2X\iff X=3\text{ or -1}\iff \log_2 (x)=3\text{ or } \log_2(x)=-1$$ You have to discard 
$\log_2(x)=-1$ because of the proposed equation.Hence $$\color{red}{x=8}$$

Answer (score 2):

1) Perform algebraic rearrangement

$$2\log_{2}(\log_{2}(x))=1+\log_{2}(\log_{2}(2\cdot 2^{0.5}x))$$

2) Apply laws of logarithms

$$\log_2((\log_2(x))^2)=\log_{2}(2\log_{2}(2\cdot 2^{0.5}x))$$

3) Raise 2 to the power of both sides

$$(\log_2(x))^2=2\log_{2}(2\cdot 2^{0.5}x)$$

4) Apply the laws of logarithms once more

$$(\log_2(x))^2=2\log_2(2\cdot2^{0.5})+2\log_2(x)=3+2\log_2(x)$$

Notice that this can be arranged into a quadratic in $\log_2(x)$, namely

$$(\log_2(x))^2-2\log_2(x)-3=0$$

which can be factored as

$$(\log_2(x)+1)(\log_2(x)-3)=0$$

Therefore, $\log_2(x)=-1$ or $\log_2(x)=3$. This is equivalent to $x=1/2$ or $x=8$. But we aren't yet done! Notice that for 1/2 to be a solution, logarithms have to be defined for negative numbers. This cannot be. Thus, 8 is the only solution.